# How to skip client side validation for draft node?

Tags: nodes, forms

I am using clientside validation module for drupal 7.I have two button for submit node one is for save as draft and other submit so Now my scenario is that if i click on save as draft then it should not display client side validation error.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a 'cancel' class to your draft button and it will skip clientside_validation, we do this out-of-the-box for the delete button, code can be found in [clientside_validation.module, line 278](http://drupalcode.org/project/clientside_validation.git/blob?f=clientside_validation.module#l278)

Comment: it is working fine after adding 'cancel' class but there is one more issue if there are some integer values and if put character values then how it will show error. because after adding class it does not checks.