# How to prevent required field validation in validation function?

Tags: forms

**Issue:** When create a node and node publish check box is checked, all validation should work (it's working fine). but when create a node and node publish check box is not checked , then all validation should skip.

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
   array_unshift($form['#validate'], 'mymodule_reqursive_unrequired');  
}

function mymodule_reqursive_unrequired(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // print_r($form);die;
    $form['actions_copy']['submit']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array();
    $form['actions']['submit']['#limit_validation_errors'] = array();

    $form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;
    $blog_images = $form['field_image_blog'][LANGUAGE_NONE];
    $form['field_page_title'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
    foreach($blog_images as $image_k => $blog_image) {
      $form['field_image_blog'][LANGUAGE_NONE][$image_k]['#required'] = FALSE;
    }
    // print_r($form);die;
}
```

Any suggestion ?

Comment: Is there any reason why you would want to avoid a non published node is validated? It is only when a node is saved that the node is validated. If you want to save a draft, there are modules for that already.

Comment: yes, want to save as draft without any validation for unpublished content.

Comment: Then, there are modules already doing that; there isn't the need to write a module just for that.

Comment: are you sure the node which is not saved yet that will not be validated? i am already using revisioning module  for moderation work. bdw can you mention the module name

Comment: this functionality is not working for saved content also. ..:( Any suggestion please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of debugging and search i get the solution.

```
function mymodule_reqursive_unrequired(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // print_r($form);die;
   if(!$form_state['values']['status']) {
     drupal_static('form_set_error', NULL, TRUE);
     drupal_get_messages();
   }  
    // print_r($form);die;
}
```

for reference [check it](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/51217/saving-a-unpublished-node-without-validation)